# Inconsistent calculation for conditional expectation

Tags: probability, integration, conditional-expectation

I'm working on a problem where I have to calculate the conditional expectation, but I get inconsistent results. I double-checked the integral calculations using Mathematica, so I think my mistake is somewhere in the integrals chosen.

We have the following joint density function: $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^y}{\log(2)} &\text{for $x,y\in(0,1)$}\\ 0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}\\f_Y(y)=\int_0^1f_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{\log(2)(y+1)}\\ \mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)=\int_0^1x\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{(y+1)(y+2)}\\ \mathbb{E}(X)=\int_0^1xf_{X,Y}(x,y)\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\frac{\log(\frac32)}{\log2}\\ \mathbb{E}(X)=\int_0^1\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)f_Y(y)\mathrm{d}y=\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\log(2)(y+1)^2(y+2)}=\frac{\frac12+\log(\frac34)}{\log2}\not=\frac{\log(\frac32)}{\log2}$$

Also, double-checking using the marginal density function $f_X$ seems to confirm $\frac{\log(\frac32)}{\log2}$ should be the right answer.

Which is clearly a contradiction. So what did I do wrong? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: When you computed $E(X\mid Y=y)$, it seems that you multiplied $xf_{X,Y}(x,y)$ by $f_Y(y)$ instead of dividing by it.

Comment: Thanks, I see! Actually this (wrong!) conditional expectation was given in the exercise, so that is the reason I overlooked it. It was given that $\mathbb{E}(X|Y=y)=\frac{1}{(y+1)(y+2)}$, which is indeed wrong. After correcting I get the right answer :)